# Empty function, what is it?

Tags: functions

I meet with term 'empty function' from time to time. It's high time to understand its nature. What is field( set of arguments) and what is image? ( set of value)?

Comment: Do you know the definition of function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set theoretic definition of a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a special type of binary relation. I.e. it is a subset of $A \times B$.
The empty set is also a subset of $A \times B$ and is defined as the empty function.

Comment: This correctly defines "empty relation", not empty function.  A function needs to be defined, uniquely, on each element of the domain.

Comment: Yeah, specifically the empty relation is a function iff $A$ is empty.